# how to call javascript function with parameter from html?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I would like to call my javascript funcion from html but idk how,

Please help me,

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (I WANT TO CALL THIS FUNCION)
    funtion condicionPci(val1){
            var PCI = '';

            if(val1<=100 && val1>=86){
                PCI = 'Excelente'; (result)
            }else if(val1<=85 && val1>=71){
                PCI = 'Muy Bueno';(result)
            }else if(val1<=70 && val1>=56){
                PCI = 'Bueno';(result)


            return PCI;(result)

        }
</script>
```

this is my HTML CODE and i want to call javascript with this foreach
here im getting all parameter in my controler but i want 
to calculate pci with a js function but can't call it 
well idk

this is my body:

```
                    @foreach($p as $dpci)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$dpci->cod_medida}}</td>

                        <td>{{$dpci->vrc}}</td>
                        <td>{{$dpci->nom_falla}}</td>
                        <td>{{$dpci->pcixpav}}</td>
                        <td onload="condicionPci({{$dpci->pcixpav}});"></td> 
                        (HERE A WANT TO CALL THE FUNCION BUT I WOULD LIKE TO 
                        SEND the parameter pcixpav)
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank,

I could solve with php

```
 <?php
 funtion condicionPci($val1){
        $PCI = '';

        if($val1<=100 && $val1>=86){
            $PCI = 'Excelente';
        }else if($val1<=85 && $val1>=71){
            $PCI = 'Muy Bueno';
        }else if($val1<=70 && $val1>=56){
            $PCI = 'Bueno';


        return $PCI;

    }
        ?>
```

HTML

```
                 @foreach($detallespci as $dpci)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$dpci->cod_medida}}</td>
                        <td>{{$dpci->vrc}}</td>
                        <td>{{$dpci->nom_falla}}</td>
                        <td>{{$dpci->pcixpav}}</td>
                        <td><?php echo condicionPci($dpci->pcixpav);?></td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
              @foreach($p as $dpci)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$dpci->cod_medida}}</td>

                    <td>{{$dpci->vrc}}</td>
                    <td>{{$dpci->nom_falla}}</td>
                    <td>{{$dpci->pcixpav}}</td>
                    <td onload="condicionPci('{{$dpci->pcixpav}}');"></td> 

                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Note: I have just added single quotes around the JS function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check this condition in your **TD** with php. If you want to check this condition by javascript then you should generate dynamic id on your deisred **TD** and pass that dynamic id parameter on your javascript function.

```
         @foreach($p as $dpci)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$dpci->cod_medida}}</td>

                <td>{{$dpci->vrc}}</td>
                <td>{{$dpci->nom_falla}}</td>
                <td>{{$dpci->pcixpav}}</td>
                <td id="{{'dynamicId-'.$dpci->id}}" onload="condicionPci('{{$dpci->pcixpav}}',{{'dynamicId-'.$dpci->id}});"></td> 

            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

On Your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
funtion condicionPci(val1,dynamicId){
        var PCI = '';

        if(val1<=100 && val1>=86){
            PCI = 'Excelente'; (result)
        }else if(val1<=85 && val1>=71){
            PCI = 'Muy Bueno';(result)
        }else if(val1<=70 && val1>=56){
            PCI = 'Bueno';(result)


        $('#'+dynamicId).html(PCI);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't bind onload event on td tag. I know this piece of code seem not well, but i think it will easy for you to understand as your way

```php
@foreach($p as $dpci)
<tr>
    <td>{{$dpci->cod_medida}}</td>
    <td>{{$dpci->vrc}}</td>
    <td>{{$dpci->nom_falla}}</td>
    <td>{{$dpci->pcixpav}}</td>
    <td><script>document.write(condicionPci({{$dpci->pcixpav}}))</script></td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
```